# Opennms URL not created

Tags: opennms

Can anyonw please explain what the following url actually means.?are there any good resource where I can learn how to generate meassuremnts api url

/opennms/rest/measurements/node%5B212%5D.hrStorageIndex[C]/hrStorageSize?start=1532328553332

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to make a url so that I can access performance parameters in opennms for one of my node

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Measurements API Documentation](http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/branches/develop/guide-development/guide-development.html#_measurements_api)

Comment: can you tell me if rrdtool and snmp have anything to do with it?beacuse I trying to find those tools in my system, it shows they r installed but cant find them

Comment: Well, yes. The Measurements API is used to extract performance data from OpenNMS and that usually takes the form of SNMP data which is stored in RRD files. The link you posted is trying to get the values from the collected hrStorageSize OID for node 212 drive C:. Thus the RRD file should be in `/var/opennms/rrd/snmp/212/hrStorageIndex/C/hrStorageSize.rrd`. Makes sense?

Comment: Oh yes...now i somwhat got it, but since I need CPU load and network related data how can I get it? Do I need to edit any of the configuration files?